# maven surfire testng execution not working

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have problems setting up my project for testng usage.
Background is that I want to execute my test.xml with maven command line.
I use this plugin within the build section of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
   <configuration>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However... when I call `mvn clean test -DxmlSuiteFile=test.xml`
all my unit tests are executed but the test.xml is untouched.

when I change the version of surefire to `2.22.2` everything works fine.
BUT I get the message: `testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value`
when running only `mvn test`

I am confused how to get that to run with the surefire 3.0.0-M5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-DxmlSuiteFile=test.xml` is not required if it already defined in pom.xml.

Try to define surefire testNG provider explicitly:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

`test.xml` file should be in the project root.

---

See also:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html